# how to avoid a join in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have kind of impossible question : i am working with teradata, i have a table from which i have to take a field, BUT i need for this to make a join with another table that does not contain a field to make a join with the first table.
So my question is : is there any way to do my request and to take the field i need with another solution than a join ? For me, it seems impossible, but maybe there is a way ( or ways) that i don't know ?

I hope that my question is clear.

PS : please don't tell me unoptimized solutions ;)

Cheers !

BLG.

Comment: Remove this question.  Then ask another question with the query that you would use to get the information you want.  Perhaps you should then ask about how to improve performance for that query.

Comment: To avoid assumptions, can you show some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: "please don't tell me unoptimized solutions ;)".  Love it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I don't have the query yet, i am still triying to write it :(

Comment: @Siyual : i can give you an example of what i want to do : i have table A with the fields 1, 2 and 3 and table B with the fields 4,5 and 6 and i want to write a request that will return fields 4,5,6 and 1 ( the fields 1,2,3,4,5,6 are all different from each others) !

Comment: @dfundako many thanks to all of you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do - select t1.f1, t2.f4, t2.f5, t2.f6 from table1 t1, table2 t2; - and if you have multiple records - it will give you all combinations between records in table1 and table2, unless this is what you were looking for at first place.